# How do I run Python 3?

Tags: 12.04, python

The description here says that 12.04 ships with python 3.2.3 as well. What command do I run to get this? Running `python -v` or `python2 -V` or `python2.7 -V` all give me the same result `2.7.3`. There are no other commands with the name `python` available. Do I have to install it?

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#PrecisePangolin.2BAC8-ReleaseNotes.2BAC8-CommonInfrastructure.Python_Toolchain

Note: I am not interested in setting python 3.2 as my default interpreter, I just want to know that if it ships, what command runs it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whether or not Python 3 is installed after installation or not depends mostly on the flavour and version. If a package depends on Python 3 it will be installed.

The best indication on whether it will come with the standard desktop installation is by checking the manifest files for the installation images.

Manifest files:

- [12.04.2 amd64 regular Unity desktop](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.2/release/ubuntu-12.04.2-dvd-amd64.manifest)
- [12.04.2 i386 regular Unity desktop](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.2/release/ubuntu-12.04.2-dvd-i386.manifest)

Both do not contain anything with `python3`. However,

- [13.04 amd64 regular Unity desktop](http://nl.releases.ubuntu.com/raring/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.manifest)

*does* have lots of `python3` packages.

This means that for 12.04 you'll probably need to install it afterwards: [python3 [image: Install python3]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/python3). Use the link to install using the Software Centre or run:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Then invoke the new Python 3 shell using

```
python3
```

Note that Python 2.7 will still be present and will stay the default.

Answer (score 25):

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Then

```
python3
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I do have to install it and it doesn't really come installed.

Comment: Yeah, I checked it when I saw your post.  It was not installed on my 64bit system by default.  I havent checked my 32bit laptop yet.